# duplicate item in room database when switch between bottom navigation and click back press button in android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In the create customer screen when I click Insert button and back to the Main(customer) screen every things ok but when I click on the another icon on the bottom navigation and then click back press to the Main(customer) screen the item was insert it will be duplicate and then I click bottom navigation again and back the item will duplicate again and again...
I use

```
<pre>onClick = {<br/>
navController.navigate(screen.route) {<br/>
popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id)<br/>
launchSingleTop = true
}<br/>
}<br/>
 BackHandler(enabled = false, onBack = {<br/>
        navController.navigate(screen.route) {<br/>
            popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id)<br/>
            { inclusive = true }<br/>
            launchSingleTop = true<br/>
        }<br/>
    })<code>
```